# Update Task's custom field with Related Custom Objects Field

Tags: trigger, custom-object

I have a custom object `Policy__c` with a lookup field `Related Policies` which is a self relationship field to `Policy__c`. Whenever a `Policy` record contains a value in the `Related Policies` field I want to update the `Tasks Corporate Client Name` with the value of the `Client Name` associated with the `Related Policies` field.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have a custom object Policy__c with a lookup field Related Policies which is a self relationship field to Policy__c .Whenever a Policie's Record contains a value in the Related Policies field I want to update the Tasks Corporate Client Name with the value of the Client Name associated with the Related Policies field.

Comment: Is task child of Policy object? if yes, I want to suggest you to try out process builder?
Although you can write a trigger if you want.